# Unable to save secure data to react-native-secure-key-store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keystore, react-native-ios

I am using 'react-native-secure-key-store' npm package to securely store session keys in React native. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-secure-key-store

When I try to save I get the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Login._this.saveSessionToken (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:81379:45)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:81370:17
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:16056:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:16157:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2884:21
    at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2773:9)
    at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2809:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:3028:14)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2362:18)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2189:18
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/5eb8f7f3-851b-47b3-8b90-107d6700bef3:2189:18
```

I followed the documentation and created a secureKeyStore.js file which looks like this.

secureKeyStore.JS

```
 import RNSecureKeyStore from 'react-native-secure-key-store';

export function storeKey ( key, value ){
    RNSecureKeyStore.set(key, value)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

export function retrieveKey(key) {
    RNSecureKeyStore.get(key)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

export function removeKey(key) {
    RNSecureKeyStore.remove(key)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }); 
}
```

This is how I am accessing these methods.

Login.JS

```
import { storeKey, retrieveKey } from '../../../utils/secureKeyStore';

storeKey('sessionToken', 'xyz');
```

package.json - dependencies

```
"react-native-secure-key-store": "^1.0.9",
```

Could you suggest where am I doing it wrong.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

Same problem ! This is my way that you may be try:

- I installed by `yarn` command. Use `npm` instead. May be yarn is error.
- Downgrade lib to `1.0.5`
- `react-native link xxxxx`.
- Delete `ios/build` folder.
- Open Xcode, Clean, Build project. If there are no error go to next
- `react-native run-ios` again.
- It's works !

Comment: i try this, but same

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the data after doing JSON.stringfy & for getting the data you need to do JSON.parse.